# Is there any sentence embedding Tensorflow language model?

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, language-model, word-embedding

I found tensorflow 1b_lm project: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/lm_1b

I'm just quite confused about the forth example

> Give a sentence, dump the embedding from the LSTM state.

However, the results of this example includes 7 '.npy' files. It seems like it just generates every word embedding for every word in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

It outputs the internal state of each step, where each step corresponds to the sentence fragment seen so far.
The last vector holds the embeddings of the whole sentence